# Using Reactjs with Styled Components - Currency Sign £ is displayed as a ? in styled button

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using a styled-components to style a botton in a react application. The botton is an add to cart button and I want the text in the button to have the currency sign next to the price.
However when I run the application it displays a ? inside a diamond instead of a £ symbol.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

This is what the browser renders:

[image]

This is the styled-component code:

```
    <AddToCartButton
data-item-id={productItem.ProductId}
data-item-price={productItem.Price}
data-item-url={productItem.ProductUrl}
data-item-description={productItem.Description}
data-item-image={productItem.ProductImageUrl}
data-item-name={productItem.ProductName}
    {...dynamicProps[i]}>
    ADD TO CART £{productItem.Price}
  </AddToCartButton>
```

and this is the definition of the styled-component:

```
export const AddToCartButton = styled(Button).attrs(() => ({
    className: 'snipcart-add-item'
}))`display:block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #009539;
    border-color: #009539;
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding-left:35px;
    padding-right:35px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:14px`
```

I'm not sure if this is something to do with CSS in genreal or a specfic problem when using styled-components.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's related to any of them, but can you replace it with `&pound;` ? also as a test, try changing your font-family property to make sure it's not related to it.

Comment: Tried both of your suggetions, none of them worked. - Very strange...